# Seleccionar un valor por defecto PHP

Tags: php, php7

Estoy intentando seleccionar un valor por defecto, este es el código

```
if($room_stock > 0){ ?>
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mt10">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-tags"></i> <?php echo $pms_texts['NUM_ROOMS']; ?></div>
                                            <select name="num_rooms[<?php echo $id_room; ?>]" class="form-control sendAjaxForm selectpicker" data-target="#room-options-<?php echo $id_room; ?>" data-extratarget="#booking-amount" data-action="<?php echo pms_getFromTemplate('common/change_num_rooms.php'); ?>?room=<?php echo $id_room; ?>">
                                                <?php
                                                for($i = 0; $i <= $room_stock; $i++){ ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                } ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
```

Esto funciona perfecto, me arroja un resultado como el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, si yo selecciono el valor 1, se me habilita estas opciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr, es que para que el cliente no tenga que seleccionar, quiero que el valor 1 sea el que este por defecto. En vez de 0 y pueda habilitar la confirmación de huéspedes.

He intentado lo siguiente.

```
if($room_stock > 0){ ?>
                                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mt10">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-tags"></i> <?php echo $pms_texts['NUM_ROOMS']; ?></div>
                                            <select name="num_rooms[<?php echo $id_room; ?>]" class="form-control sendAjaxForm selectpicker" data-target="#room-options-<?php echo $id_room; ?>" data-extratarget="#booking-amount" data-action="<?php echo pms_getFromTemplate('common/change_num_rooms.php'); ?>?room=<?php echo $id_room; ?>">
                                                <?php
                                                $i =1;
                                                ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                               
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }
```

Pero lo que consigo es que el valor aparezca seleccionado pero no se activa la confirmación del huésped.

Codigo javascript

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    
    $('select[name^="num_rooms"]').on('change', function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(obj.val() > 0){
                var attr = obj.attr('name').match(/\[(\d+)\]/);
                var target = $('select[name^="num_adults['+attr[1]+']');
                target.val('1').trigger('change');
            }
        }, 500)
    }).change();
        $('.room-options').on('change', '[name^="num_children"]', function(){
            var attr = $(this).attr('name').match(/\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/);
            var target = $('#children-options-'+attr[1]+'-'+attr[2]);
            var num = $(this).val();
            var html = '<?php echo $pms_texts['CHILDREN_AGE']; ?>:<br>';
            for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
                html +=
                '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">'+
                    '<div class="input-group-addon"><?php echo ucfirst($pms_texts['CHILD']); ?> '+(i+1)+'</div>'+
                        '<select name="child_age['+attr[1]+']['+attr[2]+']['+i+']" class="form-control sendAjaxForm selectpicker" data-extratarget="#booking-amount" data-action="<?php echo pms_getFromTemplate('common/change_num_people.php'); ?>?index='+attr[2]+'&id_room='+attr[1]+'" data-target="room-result-'+attr[1]+'-'+attr[2]+'" style="display: none;">'+
                            '<option value="">-</option>';
                            for(var j = 0; j <= 12; j++) html += '<option value="'+j+'">'+j+'</option>';
                            html +=
                        '</select>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            }
            target.html(html);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        });
        
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['room_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['room_id'])){ ?>
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('select[name="num_rooms[<?php echo $_POST['room_id']; ?>]"').val('1').trigger('change');
            }, 2000);
            <?php
        } ?>
    });
</script>
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Tenés que agregarle el atributo [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) al option que quieras.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= $room_stock; $i++) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php echo ($i == 1) ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Si, parece que la solucion que dices puede ser viable, sin embargo parece estar asociado a un evento en javascript que hace que al seleccionar la opcion 1 , se activen los campos, es un codigo que recien estoy cogiendo por alguien que no quizo documentarlo. :(

Comment: Acabe de actualizar la pregunta y le agregue el código que parece que activa la función al seleccionar el valor 1

Comment: Qué pasa si agregás un `.change()` al final de tu `onChange`? `$('select[name^="num_rooms"]').on('change', function() { ... }).change();`

Comment: Ya lo agregue pero no pasa nada.

Comment: Podrías pegar el código exacto de lo que probaste? El `change()` al final tienen que disparar el evento. Salvo que falte otra cosa.

Comment: Si, eso iba a hacer, toma 1 segundo

Comment: Listo, ya agregue la parte en la que lo puse

Comment: Estaba probando esto, dentro del select con el codigo que me pasaste, queda seleccionado 1 por defecto, y por ejemplo si vuelvo a poner 0 y luego selecciono 1 nuevamente entonces el evento si se activa, estaba pensando si en la parte de 
if(obj.val() > 0) le digo que sea =1 , que crees?

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, hice varias pruebas pero no logro conseguirlo

Comment: Tendrías que editar tu pregunta y dejar un ejemplo reproducible, sino es muy difícil que te podamos ayudar. PHP acá no tiene nada que ver, es un tema de HTML y JS. Probá por ejemplo poner dentro de la función del onChange un `console.log('algo')` y fijate si eso se dispara al cargar la página (antes de seleccionar algo).

Comment: Si ya puse el console.log, el envento no se dispara al cargar la pagina, se dispara luego de haber seleccionado en el valor en el select option.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131492/discussion-between-blackhat-and-azeos).